# Web-Based Initiation of Creation of IaaS in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to create an automation demo for customers, where I have a single page web app with a couple of input text fields, and the inputs get used as parameters in the creation of an Azure Resource Group and VNETs/VMs/etc within the Resource Group.

I can do all of the above with Azure CLI (v2.0) on my laptop, and also from CLI using a Azure CLI in a bash script on a Linux server, but I wanted something web-based. I considered standing up a web page on the Linux server to call the bash script, but that seems a bit painful (especially with permissions etc). I also thought maybe Azure Functions could provide a solution to host the single web page app and call the Azure CLI commands, but I've never used Functions before so not sure if Functions can do this; the description of Functions' capabilities aren't clear to me.

What is the best way to achieve what I'm after, quickly?

Note I'm not a developer, I'm a network engineer, so whilst I can hack around in a few languages from Notepad and vi, I'm not looking to build something in a full SDK, or have something with enterprise-level reliability, version control, etc. This is really all about proof of concept and web-based demo of something I already have in Azure CLI / bash script.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and relatively dirty way, you could create an Azure Runbook (using the scripts created from the Azure Portal) and invoke using the [Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/) This could use the scripts (or close to) what you already have.

When you roll out a new service in Azure you get the option now to download the Automation Script, you can then follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-deploy-template-runbook) to deploy the generated script via a runbook

Answer (score 0):

To follow on from Jamie's idea.

You can code your Azure Cli script (or Powershell) into an Azure Automation Runbook, you can have variables etc to access it with.

You can then attach a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) to that runbook, and call it from a standard HTTP Post request.

Meaning you could create a HTML form, that would pass whatever variables are required and build whatever is needed.

The downside of this would be that you will be creating it on your infrastructure.

You can have a solution that will deploy to someone else's infrastructure with a [deploy to Azure](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/01/17/the-deploy-to-azure-button/) button

This lets you host it in Github etc, it takes a bit more knowledge to make it work but saves your account dollars!